# Get execution time of every part of a profile plan

Tags: neo4j, metrics

Is there a way to measure the time it takes to perform each part of a Neo4j execution plan?

I can see the total execution time and total db hits. Also db hits and estimated rows for each part of the execution plan but not the time it takes to perform it. For example, the time it takes to perform a 'Filter' or 'Expand(All)' operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nop you can't.

But you have the number of dbhits on each boxes, so you are already aware of the resources consumption of each part.

Why do you want to know the time of each part ?

### Update answer after comment

A dbhit is an abstract unit of work for the database.  So more dbhit you've got on a box, more work needs to be done on it, and so it takes more time.

On the other side, an execution depends a lot of the state of your computer. Do you have a lot of processes that are using the CPU, memory, network, hard drive ... ?

So to compare time executions is bad habit, you should compare the dbhits.

DBHits are always related to the time execution of a query, but the opposite is not necessary true.

Comment: Because for wat i can see db hits are not always related to time execution